# Use MemoryCache with Singleton Pattern Without Error c#

Tags: singleton

I Use Singleton pattern for instantiate object of my class program
But When I use MemoryCache.Default for keep my variable and build my code and Deploy to server I get error randomly and the code doesnt work correctly,
For example 2 time the logic of code is correct but 1 time not working correctly,
my singleton pattern is like:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : Singleton<T>, new()
    {
        private static T _instance;
        public static T Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    return _instance = new T();
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Exact question is that may when I use singleton,,memorycache doesnt work correctly
And what is the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have your problem
I think when you use singleton for instantiate object of class
the memorycache dont work correctly and the program dont run according to the logic of code
i suggest you that create an object whenever need to object
for example instead of using

> YourClass.Instance.Method

you can instantiate object like this:

> readonly object object= new object;

and I hope your problem solve
best regard

Comment: as you mention i think memorycache is not thread safe and when i use singleton the program breakmm thanks for helping me